# Facebook Java Server

Tags: java, web-services, facebook, blackberry

Hey all, have a question for you. I have a web service written in Java that handles requests from a BlackBerry App, i want this app to be able to post to FB, but i don't want the user to be prompted to go to a website on the device to log in and be verified, i wanna do something like XAuth does with Twitter, sending username and password once to get an access token and be able to use that to do petitions to Facebook. I only need to post to the wall right now, any idea how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask the user to give you offline access to its account, then your app can post etc to the user profile even after the user has gone offline

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on how I can do this?

Comment: You need to ask the user to connect to facebook using oAuth or facebook connect like they say here on their website (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). When doing that you ask for the offline access permission. After that, your application should be able to do all operations using the social graph when the user is offline as well.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. But i believe you haven't quite understood what it is i need to do. I do not want that Allow/Do not Allow window to pop up, i just want to get the access token without prompting the user in that manner. The request is done from a BB device and it is the server that does the handling of the request so the user cannot be prompted. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: There is no way supported by facebook to do this as far as I know.

Comment: Well thank you anyways, i guess i'll have todo a workaround a didn't want to do: add a browser field to my app and prompt the user using that.